# full path must be less than 260 characters - SSRS

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, file-io, ssrs-2008

I point one of the menu items in my web application to the below path

```
http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=/Parent Reports/Child
```

Reports

When I click on it the report manager UI displays the following message:

> The path of the item '`http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=/Parent Reports/Child Reports`' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash.

Comment: twitter ? :) Sounds like the Windows C macro MAX_PATH.

Comment: You might have to do some encoding of the url to handle empty spaces.

Comment: It is not a valid path name.  It wants a file path, not a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when one of my developers were trying to edit a report in ssrs, using the [report builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767245/1501497)

the problem started when he was accessing the data source which was on a different path.

I soon as I granted that specific data source, the permissions below, it all worked fine:

[image]

Comment: On the contrary, I don't think the teddy bear question is bad and JeffUK should know better. He is in SO long enough to know the prime rule - `be nice`. Signed: a former SQL Server MVP

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a 260 path limit in Windows (or is it NTFS?).  Perhaps the path to your solution folder and child folders and file name for the aspx page that services that request is longer than 260 characters.  If this is the case, try moving the solution folder closer to the c:\ root and try again.

Comment: It's definitely **not** NTFS. In fact, the Windows kernel supports paths up to `USHORT_MAX` characters long. It's `shlwapi.dll` who's placed that silly limit on you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Windows does implement a solution to the legacy MS-DOS 260 char path limit.  It's the Long UNC path format, which starts with `\\?\` such as `\\?\c:\path\file.txt`.

If you have access to the source code of the web service producing this error, you might try digging around in the service code that converts the URL arguments into local file paths and see if tacking the \?\ on the front helps matters at all.

It also seems odd that you would get this file path error message on a URL.  Check your code (or the code of the web service) to see if somebody is using Path functions where they should be using URI functions.

Finally, note that your example contains space characters, both in the path and in the URI.  Space characters are definitely prohibited in URIs; you will need to URI escape them with %20 to make them valid URIs.  That could be the real cause of the problem - the web service is not actually receiving the whole URI you're sending, since URI parsing will stop at the first space character.