# Getting a "one or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified" error

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am building a report that I would like to accept two values from the user, feed those into a query, and find the data associated with those entries.

For example, if you had a list of employees, performance measures, and values associated with those; then the user would select an employee name / performance measure, and they would get the scoring information on that employee for that measure.

I have two parameters, each being populated from SQL queries getting a distinct list of employee names and measures, and a table below that just pulls up information based on ~ 'WHERE name = @Name AND measure = @Measure' but when I click 'Preview' to run the report locally I get the error:  "one or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified"

I know the parameters are working properly because I can feed their values directly into a textbox and the values populate correctly.  Also, if I change the query to just accept one parameter (i.e. WHERE measure = @Measure) the query works.

I'm confused as to why this error is occurring since I know my parameters are functioning and being populated properly.

Comment: I was getting this, too, but solved it by using the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556993/how-can-i-append-the-results-of-additional-queries-to-an-ssrs-report

Answer (score 11):

I experienced this behavior in .NET 4.0 using Local Reports (in .rdlc files), when one of the parameter's values was containing an emtpy string. Although setting the parameter was correct:

```
  report.SetParameters(
            new List<ReportParameter> {
                new ReportParameter("Title", Messages.Title),
                new ReportParameter("SubTitle", Messages.Subtitle))
            }
            );
```

It worked only as long as both parameters actually contained some characters, otherwise the mentioned exception was thrown.

Comment: thanks for the tip. It was exaclty my case. I also set the properties of my parameter to: allow blank value (checked), allow null value (checked)

Answer (score 8):

This error is caused when you either

**A**) the parameter is spelled wrong in the actual report. Meaning that the query is expecting @Name but the report is passing @Names (or some other spelling).

or

**B**) Is it possible you are attempting to run the report with a default value on the parameter of NULL for @Name but the stored procedure requires an actual value?

This might be happening if you are building the report in Visual Studio and gave the @Name parameter a default value of (null).

Try removing the default value or making sure you @Name parameter has an actual value, even if it's just ''.

Comment: That is what is so frustrating.  The parameter is spelled correctly, and I am not allowing default values at all.  I just tried allowing a set of default values, and the report will run once, but when you change a parameter and click 'view report' to run it again, the error reappears.

Comment: I can run the query on either of the parameters individually (pull all names associated with a measure, or pull by name), but the minute I combine them both in my query I get the error.

Comment: My query is simply: "SELECT columns FROM table
WHERE name = @sName 
AND measure = @mType" I really don't know why I am seeing this error. :/

Comment: My issue was trying to set a default value on my sub report.  A sub report parameter does require a value passed in from the parent report.  The parameter name in both the parent report and the sub report must match.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue. Issue happened when you use SharedDataSource with parameters that are to have null value. If you use same query in embeded data source, there is no problem.

Unlike embebed data source, you have to define if parameters used in query of shared data sources are allowed to have null value as highlighted in screenshot here. In my case, there are two parameters in query of shared data source, that can have null value.

[image: Set Allow Null for SharedDataSource Parameter(s)]

So after setting them to allow null, problem fixed!

Answer (score 6):

This caused me many hours of pain. Turns out that it's to do with using a shared dataset.
Embed the dataset within your report instead and it works fine.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, whether the dataset is shared or not has no relation to the issue.

Comment: @Donbecker believe it or not I experienced the exact same issue as the OP and the fix I describe (which I found in another forum) resolved it in my circumstance. I mainly left the comment here to stop others starting the same wild goose chase I did.

Comment: The only way I can think of that this would solve a dataset issue would be if your dataset definition was somehow corrupt. Any chance you could reproduce and verify?

Comment: It's my work environment so I'll give it a go on monday. Should be straight forward.

Comment: I can also confirm that this can be caused by a a shared dataset. It happened to me exactly as chris described. Do not downvote his post.

Comment: I solved this issue by going to the parent report's data source's properties, repicking the same shared datasource and clicking OK. I think it's related to having different `<rd:DataSourceID>` in dev environment than on test. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: I can confirm this freaky behaviour goes right away after changing the dataaset to be embedded instead of shared!

Comment: I know this is an old question/comment, but I wanted to point out UMAR's comment on Marcel's answer.  Check the Parameters properties screen in the menu for the Shared Dataset that is causing the issue.  Make sure that the allow nulls option is set as needed and that default values are being passed as needed.

Comment: For me, the issue was due to missing Shared dataset on the production server. Once the dataset was added to the server the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

For me, setting the value of the parameter makes problem. I don't know why, but the parameter value was not able to accept a string.Empty or null. So i just gave a " " as value solves the error.

### Sample

```
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[4];
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Name", EName);
parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("ShiftName", CurrentShift);
parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("Date", LoginDate);
if(ValidateReportData())//some condition
{
    parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("Date1", LoginDate);
}
else
{
    //parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("Date1", string.Empty);//this makes exception while calling Render function.
    parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("Date1", " ");//Solves the issue.
}
```

Comment: Correct, the empty string is make throuble,,

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, it is now sorted on sql server 2008 r2.

I know this is now an old question,
but just to help others:

It was very simple really, just making sure the spelling including the case is the same and the use of @.

I have a shared dataset called currentSpaceByDrive with the following code:

```
SELECT 
   [DRIVE]
  ,[Volume_Size_GB]
  ,[VolumeSpaceAvailable_GB]
  ,[VolumePercentAvailable]
FROM  monitoring.dbo.currentSpaceByDrive(@ServerID)
```

I add the shared dataset currentSpaceByDrive to my report and I give it the same name.
when I right click on it, the one on my report, dataset properties, the parameter is @ServerID.

@ServerID value comes from another dataset, called the_servers (where the user selects a serverID)

I have a report parameter also called @ServerID that gets its value from the_servers and is used to feed the @ServerID parameter on currentSpaceByDrive.

Too many @ServerID, I understand, but if you do your own test based on this, you will get it done.
See the image attached.

hope this helps
marcelo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check DataSet In Report Server , I had Similar Problem , I was Editing Shared Dataset in Visual Studio , but it didn't work , after an hour of frustration I checked dataset in report server and I found out it Is not updating with changes I made in visual studio , I Delete it and Redeploy Dataset Again from visual studio . it works .

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had to:

- Delete the SubReport object from the report.
- Drag new object from Toolbox
- Setup the SubReport name and report
- In Paramateres "Add", and choose each parameter, and related value.

Then is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have same issue my Parameter Supervisor is blank when I choose "Select All" which causes the error "One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport", but if I select a few supervisor name then the sub-report appears. It is puzzling because the Manager parameter value shows all value when "Select All" is checked, but it is not working on my Supervisor parameter. Note that Supervisor parameter is dependent on manager parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using shared DataSets for several reports, and the root cause of this issue was not mapping the input parameters from the report itself to the parameters of the shared dataset.

To fix, I navigated to the "Report Data" panel, opened the dataset (which is really linking to a shared dataset), clicked the "Parameter" tab, and then mapped the report parameters to the parameters of the shared dataset.