# SSRS "LoadSubreportDefinition" Getting Error "One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I created a `.rdlc` report with Visual Studio 2013, let's called it `Main.rdlc` and it has subreport control in it.

On the other hand, I created a `Sub.rdlc` as a subreport to be linked with `Main.rdlc`

I set the subreport path on the code behind with this code:

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

// load report definition
string reportTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/Main.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(ReportLocalizator.Localize(reportTemplate, culture));
viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true; 
viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Culture", culture));

// load subreport definition
viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += LocalReport_SubreportProcessing;
string subReportTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/Sub.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("SubReport", ReportLocalizator.Localize(subReportTemplate, culture));

viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyDataSet", myDataSet.Data.DefaultView));
viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string mimeType = string.Empty;
string encoding = string.Empty;
string extension = string.Empty;

byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.HeaderEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bytes.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=PrintedForm" + "." + extension);
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // create the file  
Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download  
Response.End();
```

But, I always get an error "**One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified.**" though the subreport has no parameter in it.

The code is running well when I remove this part

```
// load subreport definition
viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += LocalReport_SubreportProcessing;
string subReportTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/Sub.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("SubReport", ReportLocalizator.Localize(subReportTemplate, culture));
```

Is it the code that causing error or the rdlc itself? Does anybody has an experience about this error? Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I assume you are selecting some parameters before you then run the report and then click through to your sub report. The above code is running the main report and then running the sub report before the sub report gets the params from the main report.

Comment: Hi @Snowlockk, thanks for ur reply. I didn't selecting any parameters before running the report. The only parameter that set on the code behind is `culture` - and there's no parameter fields on the subreport. Did you find any clue from that code?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140176/getting-a-one-or-more-parameters-required-to-run-the-report-have-not-been-speci

Comment: Hi @Raphael, thanks for your comment. I've take a look on that post and got an insight from that. I realized that the problem is in my code. It has been fixed for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the code. The error is telling that there's a missing parameter in the main report.

It's because I call  the `SetParameters` before the `LoadSubReportDefinition` call.

I'm not sure why, but calling `LoadSubReportDefinition` seems clearing any parameters that you have been set before.

So the solution is moving `SetParameters` call after the `LoadSubReportDefinition`

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

// load report definition
string reportTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/Main.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(ReportLocalizator.Localize(reportTemplate, culture));
viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true; 

// The problem is here! Move it after LoadSubreportDefinition
// viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Culture", culture));

// load subreport definition
viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += LocalReport_SubreportProcessing;
string subReportTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/Sub.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("SubReport", ReportLocalizator.Localize(subReportTemplate, culture));

// Move it here!
viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Culture", culture));

viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyDataSet", myDataSet.Data.DefaultView));
viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: what did u put in ReportLocalizator?